# Sequelize belongsToMany with second belongsToMany table - set at once

Tags: javascript, mysql, sequelize.js, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have the following tables

```
const Employee = db.define('employee', {
  ...
})

const CapabilityType = db.define('capabilityType', {
  ...
})

const Capability = db.define('capability', {
  id: {type: Sequelize.INTEGER, autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true, unique: true},
  since: {type: Sequelize.DATEONLY, allowNull: true},
  comment: {type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: true}
})

const UploadFile = db.define('file', {
  ...
})

Employee.belongsToMany(CapabilityType, {through: Capability})
Capability.belongsToMany(UploadFile, {through: 'capabilityFiles'})
```

So it means an employee can have many capabilityTypes. This is done through the capability table. But one capability can have multiple files associated to. So it has another belongstomany through the extra 'capabilityFiles' table added.

I reached adding capabilities with additional data like this:

```
const caps = capabilities.map(c => {
  const ct = CapabilityType.build({id: c.capabilityTypeId}, {isNewRecord: false})
  ct.capability = {since: c.since, comment: c.comment}
  return ct
})
Employee.build({id: employeeId}, {isNewRecord: false}).setCapabilityTypes(caps)
```

I also tried adding files: c.files to the capability object, but that did not solve the problem.

Can somebody help me?